# In Sublime - how to switch between panels in a 2-column view?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3

Does anyone know how to - using the Sublime 3 text editor - use keyboard commands to toggle back and forth between columns in a 2-column view?  I haven't been able to find any documentation or Stack Exchange posts that describes how to do this.

thanks

Answer (score 28):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>column number</kbd> will set the active column to the column number you choose, so with 2 columns you'd use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-></kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd><-</kbd>.

Comment: Glad to help. Take a look at the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38447556/4326495) by @VortixDev too. It's only one key combination and the only time it doesn't work for me is with certain syntaxes that override the shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer a single key shortcut for each of move left and move right, then you can add it in to "Preferences" --> "Key Bindings" --> "User", e.g. for `ctrl + shift + page up/page down` you would add:

```
[
  { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+pageup"], "command": "focus_neighboring_group", "args": {"forward": false} },
  { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+pagedown"], "command": "focus_neighboring_group" },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> to toggle between panes.

Comment: For me (on Sublime 3.2.2) this requires `Command ⌘` + **`Shift`** + `[` / `]`